# Assert not raising ValueError

Tags: python, import, pytest, assert, valueerror

Edit:After diagnosing the problem with the failure of the ValueError assertion, I edited my code based on the comments, however, the code won't raise the exceptions now. What is wrong with the code that can be fixed?

**Actual code:**

```
def main():
    fraction=input("Fraction: ")
    fraction_converted=convert(fraction)
    output=gauge(fraction_converted)
    print(output)


def convert(fraction):
    while True:
        try:
            X,Y=fraction.split("/")
            x=int(X)
            y=int(Y)
            f=x/y
            if f<=1:
                p=int(f*100)
                return p
            else:
                fraction=input("Fraction: ")
                pass

  
        except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
            raise

def gauge(percentage):
    if percentage<=1:
        return "E"
    elif percentage>=99:
        return "F"
    else:
        return str(percentage)+"%"


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**Test code:**

```
from fuel import convert, gauge
import pytest

def test_correct_input():
    assert convert("1/2")==50 and gauge(50)=="50%"
    assert convert("1/4")==25 and gauge(25)=="25%"
    assert convert("0/4")==0 and gauge(0)=="E"
    assert convert("4/4")==100 and gauge(100)=="F"

def test_zero_division():
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        convert("1/0")

def test_value():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("cat/dog")
```

Comment: what is the implementation of `convert`? Does it actually raise `ValueError`?

Comment: Yes, it raises `ValueError`. This is the exact failure message:  OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`. @StrangeSorcerer

Comment: Please edit your _question_ instead of putting that into a comment, where it is unreadable.

Comment: " pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!" Exactly as it says. The `convert` function **should not** try to prompt the user for input again, in the exception handling. In fact, it should not try to loop, or handle the exception at all. That is the responsibility of the calling code. The error from the test framework tells you exactly the problem: the test says "if I try to `convert("cat/dog")`, it should raise an exception; but instead it asks me for input".

Comment: It **does not matter** that there is a `raise`, because that cannot happen until after the `input` is provided, and `pytest` has no way to provide a response to that prompt. Code provided to unit tests should not be interactive. Assuming the course gave you these tests to run, it should have also clearly explained the design requirements for `convert`; so I'm voting to close this as a typo/not reproducible (i.e. not reading the assignment carefully).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will try to re-write the code keeping that in mind. But I'm just confused why despite the problem stated by you, the ZeroDivisionError test is passing?

Comment: Your zero division test passes a number instead of a string, and does the zero division right in the test - so the exception is raised while evaluating the arguments, and you never enter your function.

Comment: Ok I've updated the code now and am editing the question to reflect that. Now the code won't raise the exceptions. What am I doing wrong? @MrBeanBremen

Comment: If you indeed use the current code, it should work - I just tested it. Note that you still don't test the `ZeroDivisionError` correctly, as you don't pass a string.

Comment: I've fixed the test code now. Thank you very much, your comments were really helpful @MrBeanBremen. My understanding of using _raise_ for exceptions was not correct but now I know.